# Under Windows CE, how can I check which RAM based DLLs are loaded in virtual memory space?

Tags: windows-mobile, memory-management, windows-ce

I have a problem with loading a DLL under Windows Mobile 5.0. I'm pretty confident that this is caused by running out of the application virtual memory (the 32 MB slot of the process, as explained in [Windows CE .NET Advanced Memory Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836325.aspx)).

I'm looking for a way to actually make sure that this is the issue and investigate whether my efforts bring expected results. Do you know of a way to check the contents of the virtual memory application slot? Any applications that can help me with this task?

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found an [entry on Windows CE team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ce_base/archive/2006/01/11/511883.aspx) about WinCE memory management/reporting tools. I'm having a look at DevHealth.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use the [toolhelp32 api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450774.aspx) to read all the virtual memory allocations, modules etc of a process. I ended up writing a tool a long time ago using those apis to read the loaded modules of all the processes on the device, plus their virtual memory usage so I could get an idea if the device was experiencing what we knew as 'dllcrunch' where the load point for the next dll in our process happens to be in our heap space, so we were getting OOM errors when loading the dll, even though there was heaps of room spare